# One of my menuItem icons stays black even if it is dark mode. Others are white as they should be

Tags: android, kotlin

My problem is that one of my menuItem icons stays black even if it is dark mode. Others are white as they should be. That is a huge problem for me because grid layout icon is not visible to users in dark mode. i want it to be white in dark mode, black in white mode. how can i achieve this behaviour? any answer is appreciated guys thank you
[in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztI4y.jpg)

I'm using a toolbar in my MainActivity file

I'm using Kotlin.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        // Retrieve NavController from the NavHostFragment
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        drawer = binding.drawerLayout

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.note_list, R.id.trash, R.id.archive), drawer)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)

        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
        
        binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            invalidateOptionsMenu()

            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.nav_notes -> {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.note_list)
                }
                R.id.nav_trash -> {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.trash)
                }
                R.id.nav_archive -> {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.archive)
                }
            }
            true
        }

        //binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)

        //
        //val drawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.open, R.string.close)
        //drawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        //drawerToggle.syncState()

        //binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        //    onNavItemSelect(it)
        //}
    }
```

I tried to programmatically fix the issue but then i decided that it is a bad way to fix because its not following any of the updated guidelines. if you have a solution that works, even if it is programmatically, i'll give it a try so any help is appreciated.